# Filtrar arrays en Js con condiciones

Tags: javascript, array

paso a explicar cual es la idea que tengo en mente. Quiero crear un "Programa" donde pueda ver cuales son las materias pendientes del plan de estudio, las materias cursadas y las materias disponibles.

La diferencias de materias pendientes y disponibles se refiere a que las pendientes son las "no cursadas" y las disponibles son las "no cursadas" pero sus correlativas aprobadas. Es decir no puedo dar por ejemplo Ingles III si no di Ingles II.

Tengo un arrays que contienen objetos (codigo de la materia, nombre de la materia, correlativas(es un array donde estara los codigos de las materias) y estado (Cursado, pendiente))

```
{
    codigo: 2401,
    materia: "Derecho Publico",
    correlativas: [],
    estado: "Cursado"
},
{
    codigo: 2402,
    materia: "Derecho Comercial I",
    correlativas: [2401],
    estado: "Pendiente"
}
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente como puedo codificar que en cada materia con estado "pendiente" filtre su correlativa y ver el estado de esa materia. Si es "cursado" entonces me lo muestre. El problema es cuando tengo mas de dos correlativas. Por ejemplo:

```
{
    codigo: 2401,
    materia: "Derecho Publico",
    correlativas: [],
    estado: "Cursado"
},
{
    codigo: 2403,
    materia: "Derecho Comercial II",
    correlativas: [2402],
    estado: "Pendiente"
},
{
    codigo: 2404,
    materia: "Contabilidad Básica",
    correlativas: [],
    estado: "Cursado"
},
{
    codigo: 2405,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación",
    correlativas: [2404],
    estado: "Pendiente"
},
{
    codigo: 2406,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación II",
    correlativas: [2405],
    estado: "Pendiente"
},
{
    codigo: 2406,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación III",
    correlativas: [2404,2405],
    estado: "Pendiente"
},
{
    codigo: 2407,
    materia: "Derecho contable",
    correlativas: [2404,2401],
    estado: "Pendiente"
}
```

Lo que pude codificar y no me funciono ya que solo me muestra las materias disponibles con solo una correlativa es lo siguiente

```js
const array2 = [
    {
        codigo: 2401,
        materia: "Derecho Publico",
        correlativas: [],
        estado: "Cursado"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2402,
        materia: "Derecho Comercial I",
        correlativas: [2401],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2403,
        materia: "Derecho Comercial II",
        correlativas: [2402],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2404,
        materia: "Contabilidad Básica",
        correlativas: [],
        estado: "Cursado"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2405,
        materia: "Tecnicas de valuación",
        correlativas: [2404],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2406,
        materia: "Tecnicas de valuación II",
        correlativas: [2405],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2406,
        materia: "Tecnicas de valuación III",
        correlativas: [2404,2405],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    },
    {
        codigo: 2407,
        materia: "Derecho contable",
        correlativas: [2404,2401],
        estado: "Pendiente"
    }
]

document.write("<br>" + '<b>Materias Disponibles</b>' + "<br><br>")
    
for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].estado == "Pendiente") {
        const varCorrelativa = parseInt(array2[i].correlativas)
        const numero = array2.find(elemento => elemento.codigo == varCorrelativa)
        if(numero.estado == "Cursado"){
            document.write(array2[i].codigo + " " + array2[i].materia + " " + array2[i].correlativas +  "<br>")
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco a los que puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien el problema, lo que quieres es mostrar solo las materias **Pendientes** pero que tengan sus respectivas materias correlativas **Cursadas** (o lo que en otras palabras mencionas, son las **Disponibles**).

Para ello primero buscamos las materias **Pendientes**, que son aquellas con `estado === 'Pendiente'`.

```javascript
const materiasPendientes = materias.filter(materia => materia.estado === 'Pendiente');
```

Luego de estas materias **Pendientes**, quieres obtener las que están **Disponibles**, o aquellas en las que todas sus **Correlativas** están con `estado === 'Cursado'`. Esto se puede lograr reduciendo las `materiasPendientes` e identificando si todas las materias que aparecen en sus `correlativas` se encuentran con `estado === 'Cursado'`. Si encontramos una materia correlativa con `estado === 'Pendiente'` entonces la materia "padre" no puede ser una materia **Disponible**.

```javascript
const materiasDisponibles = materiasPendientes.reduce((materiasD, materia) => {
  const correlativasCursadas = materia.correlativas.reduce((todasCursadas, correlativa) => {
    const correlativaInfo = materias.find(materia => materia.codigo === correlativa);
    return todasCursadas && correlativaInfo.estado === 'Cursado';
  }, true);

  if (correlativasCursadas) {
    materiasD.push(materia);
  }

  return materiasD;
}, []);
```

Conjuntando todo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
function mostrarMaterias(mensaje, materias) {
  document.write(`<br><b>${mensaje}</b><br><br>`);
  materias.forEach(materia => document.write(`${materia.codigo} ${materia.materia} [${materia.correlativas}]<br>`));
}

const materias = [
  {
    codigo: 2401,
    materia: "Derecho Publico",
    correlativas: [],
    estado: "Cursado"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2402,
    materia: "Derecho Comercial I",
    correlativas: [2401],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2403,
    materia: "Derecho Comercial II",
    correlativas: [2402],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2404,
    materia: "Contabilidad Básica",
    correlativas: [],
    estado: "Cursado"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2405,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación",
    correlativas: [2404],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2406,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación II",
    correlativas: [2405],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2406,
    materia: "Tecnicas de valuación III",
    correlativas: [2404, 2405],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  },
  {
    codigo: 2407,
    materia: "Derecho contable",
    correlativas: [2404, 2401],
    estado: "Pendiente"
  }
];

mostrarMaterias('Todas las Materias', materias);

const materiasPendientes = materias.filter(materia => materia.estado === 'Pendiente');

// console.log('Todas las Materias Pendientes');
// console.log(materiasPendientes);
mostrarMaterias('Todas las Materias Pendientes', materiasPendientes);

const materiasDisponibles = materiasPendientes.reduce((materiasD, materia) => {
  const correlativasCursadas = materia.correlativas.reduce((todasCursadas, correlativa) => {
    const correlativaInfo = materias.find(materia => materia.codigo === correlativa);
    return todasCursadas && correlativaInfo.estado === 'Cursado';
  }, true);

  if (correlativasCursadas) {
    materiasD.push(materia);
  }

  return materiasD;
}, []);

// console.log('Materias Pendientes con Correlativas Cursadas');
// console.log(materiasDisponibles);
mostrarMaterias('Materias Pendientes con Correlativas Cursadas (Disponibles)', materiasDisponibles);
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

correlativas dentro de array2 es un array de números, por lo que no tiene sentido convertirlo a entero.

Iterando sobre el array de correlativas creo que traerá el resultado esperado. Realicé una pequeña modificación agregando el for para iterar sobre las correlativas, pero según veo solo se imprimen las correlativas cursadas, no las pendientes, esto depende de tu requerimiento puntual.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].estado == "Pendiente") {
        for(let varCorrelativa of array2[i].correlativas) {
            let numero = array2.find(elemento => elemento.codigo == varCorrelativa)
            if (numero.estado == "Cursado") {
                document.write(array2[i].codigo + " " + array2[i].materia + " " + varCorrelativa  + "<br>")
            }
        }
    }
}
```